# Google Analytics - Multiple pages and single header

Tags: html, google-analytics

My webpage is compose from more "pages". For example:

```
www.webpage.com/home.php
www.webpage.com/registration.php
www.webpage.com/contacts.php
...etc
```

But all my pages have the same , because I include the same head in all of my pages.
My question so far:

1.) Is good to place the google analytics script in my head?

2.) If someone goes from www.webpage.com/home.php to www.webpage.com/registration.php it will count it as two visit of my page?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

its okay to place google analytics script in your head. google analytics is java script and is run only after the page is loaded into your browser. So each page will be individually recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Google actually recommends](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en) to put the code in the header

> Paste your snippet (unaltered, in its entirety) into every web page
>   you want to track. Paste it immediately before the closing 
>   tag.

One of the reasons is that GA has a report on page timings. The timer is started when the tracking code is loaded, so if you insert the code later in the page the timing reports might be off.

If you have the tracking code in all pages and GA can set cookies properly then the two calls to the pages will be tracked as two pageviews, but only one session/visit.